# Terraform aws: Missing required argument

Tags: terraform

Someone can help to clarify how local and global variables working in Terraform ? I'm facing now this issue :

> Error: Missing required argument
> │
> │   on main.tf line 46, in module "pub-rt":
> │   46: module "pub-rt" {
> │
> │ The argument "vpc_cidr_block" is required, but no definition was found.

My code structure is :

```
-- Dev
  -- main.tf
-- modules
  -- rt
    -- pub-rt.tf
    -- pri-rt.tf
    -- vars.tf
```

This is my **main.tf**

```
module "pub-rt" {
  source            = "../modules/rt"
  id1               = var.id1         #id1 will be common for pub-rt.tf & pri-rt.tf resources
  id2               = var.id2         #id2 will be used only in pub-rt.tf resources
}

module "pri-rt" {
  source            = "../modules/rt"
  id3               = var.id3         #id3 will be common for pub-rt.tf & pri-rt.tf resources
  id4               = var.id4         #id4 will be used only in pri-rt.tf resources
}
```

My ../rt/**vars.tf** contains :

```
variable "id1" { }
variable "id2" { }
variable "id3" { }
variable "id4" { }
```

Adding my real code for main.tf :

```
# Create Public Route Table
module "pub-rt" {
  source            = "../modules/rt"
  pub_rt_tag        = { Name = "prod-pub-rt" }
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  ir_cidr           = var.ir_cidr                                 # routing inside the VPC
  gateway_id        = module.igw.igwId                            # routing to the internet through igw
}


# Create Private Route Table
module "pri-rt" {
  source            = "../modules/rt"
  pub_rt_tag        = { Name = "prod-pri-rt" }
  vpc_id            = module.vpc.vpcId 
  vpc_cidr_block    = var.vpc_cidr_block                          # routing inside the VPC
  nat_id            = module.nat.natId                            # routing to the internet NAT
}
```

Comment: In `main.tf` I do not see any reference `vpc_cidr_block`. Did you miss it in your post? Have the variables in `vars.tf` a value or you reported them empty for simplicity?

Comment: `main.tf` is just an example to illustrate the issue.  In vars.tf, as example, let's say : `id1="myId1"`. The main question, how can I user variable id2 in pub-rt.tf resource file and  id4 in pri-rt.tf resource file ?

Comment: What about the first question of mine?

Comment: main.tf I do not see any reference vpc_cidr_block. Did you miss it in your post?  => please, refer to real code ... I have updated main.tf

Comment: You did not declare `var.vpc_cidr_block` anywhere.

Comment: ohh I see thanks. No I declared it and still geetting other issues : PS E:\GitRepo\Terraform\prod> terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 56, in module "pri-rt":
│   56: module "pri-rt" {
│
│ The argument "gateway_id" is required, but no definition was found.

Comment: "gateway_id" is required only in module "pub-rt", why I need to putt it in module "pri-rt" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232629/discussion-between-bhamichi-and-antonio-petricca).

Comment: Try to comment the module `pri-rt` to see **terraform** show the error for `pub-rt`. It may be an evaluation precedence issue.

Comment: this is what I get when comment "pri-rt" ================================                                                                      
PS E:\GitRepo\Terraform\prod> terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 46, in module "pub-rt":
│   46: module "pub-rt" {
│
│ The argument "vpc_cidr_block" is required, but no definition was found.

Comment: The argument "vpc_cidr_block" is required only for "pri-rt", why I must define it. Is it because it's present in "vars.tf"? please, note my "vars.tf" contains variables for both "pri-rt" and "pub-rt"